# DataGridView WrapMode + AutoSizeColumnsMode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

How do I wrap my `DataGridView's` headers **(long texts without break line)** at the same time have it's **AutoSizeColumnsMode** to Fill?

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    DataGridView1.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
Next
```

I have this code to wrap the text, but will ignore my `DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill` (*which leaves my DataGridView with empty gray spaces*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `.AutoSizeMode` property for every column in your `DataGridView`; to resolve your problem you can set `.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill` on one column (i.e. the last **visible** column).

You must also set `.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` property to specify that a textual content in a DataGridView cell is wrapped to subsequent lines or truncated when it is too long to fit on a single line.

Code example:

```
YourDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = False

For i As Integer = 0 To YourDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
    If i = YourDataGridView.Columns.Count - 2 Then
        YourDataGridView.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    Else
        YourDataGridView.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
    End If
Next i
```

Please note that I use `YourDataGridView.Columns.Count - 2` because my last column is not visible so I need to apply this property to the previous column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But still it doesn't wrap the column headers' text. :( I put this code in the last column already DataGridView1.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill

Comment: Answer update. I try the code I posted and it works. Please verify the .Visible property of your last column.

Comment: My header's text is "Vehicle Type" and "Type" is still below Vehicle. :( I guess it still doesn't work for me. :( Sorry for this.

Comment: ah ok, this is another problem: see my updated answer. good luck! ;)

Comment: Perfect! I've tried WrapMode = False before but didn't work this way. I guess it conflicted with my other layouting codes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can set WrapMode on various DataGridView elements: maybe you've set it on DefaultCellStyle and not on ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle. Sorry but at first I understood that the real problem is that you lost your Fill column...